# Spring Data Rest Neo4j: Template must not be null or empty

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

I am creating what I believe to be a fairly simple domain model in Spring.

```
@NodeEntity
class Dependency {
    @GraphId
    private Long id
    String groupId
    String artifactId
    String version

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(type = "DEPENDS_ON", direction = OUTGOING)
    Set<Dependency> dependencies = new HashSet<Dependency>()
}
```

note* the above is written in groovy.

I have also created a subsequent Repository (all textbook so far!).

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "dependency", path = "dependency")
interface DependencyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Dependency, Long> {
    List<Dependency> findByArtifactId(@Param("artifactId") String artifactId)
}
```

And finally the application class....

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "io.byteshifter.depsgraph")
@SpringBootApplication
class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public Application() {
        setBasePackage("io.byteshifter.depsgraph")
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("target/dependency.db")
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

Now I would expect when I fire the following payload at http://127.0.0.1:8080/dependency that it would create all the objects and relationships..

```
{
        "groupId": "group1",
        "artifactId": "artifact1",
        "version": "1.0",
        "dependencies" : [
            {"groupId": "group2", "artifactId": "artifact2", "version": "2.0"}, 
            {"groupId": "group3", "artifactId": "artifact3", "version": "3.0"} 
        ]
}
```

Instead, I get..

```
{
  "cause": {
    "cause": {
      "cause": null,
      "message": "Template must not be null or empty!"
    },
    "message": "Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: io.byteshifter.depsgraph.domain.Dependency[\"dependencies\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0])"
  },
  "message": "Could not read JSON: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: io.byteshifter.depsgraph.domain.Dependency[\"dependencies\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: io.byteshifter.depsgraph.domain.Dependency[\"dependencies\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0])"
}
```

I have no doubt this is a lack of understanding on my behalf. If anyone could help steer me in the right direction that would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

My REST knowledge has failed me. I should have been using a URI to represent other dependencies. See below:

```
{
        "groupId": "group3",
        "artifactId": "artifact3",
        "version": "1.0",
        "dependencies": ["http://127.0.0.1:8080/dependency/0", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/dependency/1", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/dependency/2"]
}
```